# java project imported with svn override path files

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, gwt

I'm currently working with a java project(with GWT). The versioning program is svn and I use it through the eclipse plugin.

Now, I have two machines. Today I tried to download the svn repository to the other machine (the one with no project, yet, in it). After the download, the project expected all the jar/configuration files to be found at the exact same path of the first machine.

Example:

Machine1's jar path:

```
/home/user/application/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine/other_stuff
```

Machine2's jar path:

```
/hd/another_user/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine/other_stuff
```

When I download the repository, the path of Machine1 is somehow "hard-coded" into the project, and, obviously, all the jar files aren't found.
There's a way I can tell the svn repository not to download those path file?

Answer (score 1):

Don't check in `.classpath` file into `SVN` repository.

Machine1's jar path is some where defined in class path and Machine2 is also trying to find it there.

OR

If classpath is having Machine1's jar path then just change it on Machine2 as simple as it is. you are using external jars that's why you are facing this problem. Put all the required jars in project itself and refer from there. It will solve your problem no matter on what machine you are working.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
I tried that but now when I download the repository I get this errore message:
    Errors occurred during the build:
        Building workspace
        Validating GWT components

    Details:
        Errors running builder 'java builder' on project 
        'myProject'.
        java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: What error message? set java build path in eclipse to resolve any dependencies related to class path.

Comment: No problem. Eclipse tries to build the project automatically but at this time project dependencies are not resolved. Go to Project -> properties - > java build path and add the required jars.

Comment: There is a way I can configure the repository to download the correct .classpath?
Because I remember that the first time I downloaded the project there were no need to configure anything!

Comment: If classpath is having Machine1's jar path then just change it on Machine2 as simple as it is. you are using external jars that's why you are facing this problem. Put all the required jars in project itself and refer from there. It will solve your problem no matter on what machine you are working.